# Cannot drag image inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drag-and-drop

i created a div an want to drag & drop pictures in it... the main problem is, that if it works the image cannot be dragged inside that div.

**Code working drag & drop**

```
 $('div[role="textbox"]').on(
    'dragover',
    function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
        );
    $('div[role="textbox"]').on(
        'dragenter',
        function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
        }
    );


    $('div[role="textbox"]').on(
    'drop',
    function (e) {

});
```

Code drag & drop not working but drag inside div works

```
//$('div[role="textbox"]').on(
    //'dragover',
    //function (e) {
    //    e.preventDefault();
    //    e.stopPropagation();
    //}
    //    );
    //$('div[role="textbox"]').on(
    //    'dragenter',
    //    function (e) {
    //        e.preventDefault();
    //        e.stopPropagation();
    //    }
    //);


    $('div[role="textbox"]').on(
    'drop',
    function (e) {
//logic
})
```

Is there a way to combine these two to make both work?

The image is simply inserted as an .

Comment: Where is your HTML code ??

Comment: did not thought that this was neccessary because the main problem is that "drageenter" prevents dragging inside div BUT provides drag & drop inside div. and i want both :)

Comment: Please create a fiddle to help analyse your problem better.

Comment: Is there still help required on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This should be an example of what you want to do:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
        <head>
            <script>
                function allowDrop(ev){ev.preventDefault()}

                function drag(ev){ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id)}

                function drop(ev){
                    ev.preventDefault();
                    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
                    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
                }
            </script>
        </head>

        <body>
            <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
            <img id="drag1" src="img_logo.gif" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">
        </body>
    </html>
```

Source:
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp

Also from my cross browser experience, to drag/drop nested elements inside a div one needs to cancel all its drag events on the parent div.

```
element.ondragenter = function(event){event.preventDefault()};
element.ondragleave = function(event){event.preventDefault()};
element.ondragover = function(event){event.preventDefault()};
```